# Elementary Probability: What is the probability of picking a permutation of the letters NUMBER which starts and ends with a vowel?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

> What is the probability of picking a permutation of the letters NUMBER which starts and ends with a vowel?

I thought that the there are two situations: when the u is in front and when the e is in front. When the e is in front, there are $4!$ different combinations and the same for when the u is in front. I therefore concluded that the answer must be $$\frac{4! \cdot 2}{6!} = \frac{1}{15}$$ but my book says $1/45$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I agree with you. No idea where the book's answer comes from.

Comment: hmm ok seems a little odd

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct, and orthodox, but keep alert for problems that ask for **probability** because often it will be easier to directly compute the probability.

P(one vowel at front and another at the back) $= \dfrac26\dfrac15 =\dfrac1{15}$